# Can't find the meaning of "Grecar" / "Grecando"

Tags: gramática, vocabulario

My friend and I were having a conversation and she used the word "grecando" and I can't seem to find the translation anywhere.

Context: "Estoy grecando este alebrije".

Thank you always!

Answer (score 4):

> [greca](https://dem.colmex.mx/Ver/greca): adorno que repite linealmente una misma combinación de elementos geométricos, generalmente formados por ángulos rectos

> [alebrije](https://dem.colmex.mx/Ver/alebrije): escultura artesanal, generalmente pequeña, hecha de papel, cartón o madera de copal, muy colorida, que comúnmente representa animales fantásticos

Si es eso lo que te dijo, lo más probable es que haya generado el verbo a partir del primero de los sustantivos del cual recurrí a la definición. En este caso no hay mucho más que sea necesario aclarar, pero si aún necesitás un *traduttore*:

> Estoy grecando este alebrije --> *Estoy decorando esta estatua con forma de animal*

[Más información sobre los alebrijes](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alebrije)

Answer (score 0):

**"Estoy grecando este alebrije"**.

Estoy decorando o adornando esta figura de papel o de madera con colores vivos.

> I am decorating or adorning this paper or wooden figure with bright
> colors.

La locución **Grecar** no existe en el diccionario. Esta reconversión en verbo de una palabra, en este caso de la voz "greco-greca", que significa "adorno o decorado" pasa con frecuencia en muchos lugares de Iberoamérica. En este caso, en México "grecar" viene a significar embellecer, pintar, decorar o adornar algo.

> The locution **Grecar** does not exist in the dictionary. This
> reconversion of a word into a verb, in this case from the word
> "greco-greca", which means "ornament or decoration" happens frequently
> in many places in Iberoamerica. In this case, in Mexico "**grecar**" comes to mean
> to beautify, paint, decorate or adorn something.

**Alebrije** 1. m. Méx. Figura de papel maché, madera o barro, pintada de colores vivos, que representa un animal imaginario.

> **Alebrije** 1. m. Mex. Papier-mâché, wood or clay figure, painted in bright colors, representing an imaginary animal.

Comment: Why do you provide the translation of every single answer? We don't say adorn a paper. I hate to criticize you but this happens all the time...

Comment: Hola Lambie, ¡ cuanto tiempo ! Espero que te encuentres bien. Gracias por tu comentario, si eres tan amable puedes traducirme "Estoy decorando o adornando esta figura de papel o de madera con colores vivos. ", para poder escribirlo correctamente. Gracias y cuídate.

Comment: Vale, Diego. Pero hay problemas con el español tambien. I'm embellishing this origami figure with bright colors. No creo que hace falt decorar Y adornar. No creo que un color adorne algo. :)

Comment: ¡Hola Lambie! ¿No crees que los colores adornan o embellecen las cosas? ... Bueno como tu desees, si quieres o no deseas embellecerla, lo asumiré, es tu frase. Luego no digas que a la oración le falta color o que ha salido poco favorecida o "chuchurrida" .  :)

Comment: adornar es colocar adornos, no creo que la pintura sea un adorno. :)kl-1`;l.

Comment: ¡Vaya!, pensaba que cuando las mujeres se pintaban los labios o se maquillaban el rostro o se daban sombras alrededor de los ojos, es que se estaban adornando y embelleciendo. En fin, ¡qué cosas aprende uno cada día! ¡Cuídate! (っ◔◡◔)